# Will Unikong be available after April 1st?

Tags: feature-request, unikong

Once we're done pranking each other in a couple of days, will Unikong be placed someplace we can keep on playing it? I'm pretty busy, and I'm afraid I might not be able to vicariously experience Jon Skeet's epic reputation to satisfy my lowly rank-and-file soul before April Fool's Day has come and gone.

Comment: According to the [unikong tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/unikong/info), there is a tag missing in this question ;)

Comment: I think it just disappeared from SO. Unikong disappeared at around 5:30 (+5:30 IST)

Comment: It is funny to see the older question be marked duplicate of a [newer one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320262/will-unikong-be-open-sourced) :D This question's post time: 2016-04-01 01:52:25Z, and other question's post time: 2016-04-01 10:22:09Z. I just typed the times as shown when hovering *asked*.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ I flagged my question to be closed as a dup when the other post was suggested in [Alexander O'Mara's post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320241/473792). So it's a little funny, but I volunteered for this state of affairs myself because I think it makes sense to link the two threads together =)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### Update 2:

Apparently the game has gone offline, at-least temporarily, but as they say, the internet is forever.

> https://unikong.github.io/

---

Assuming this link does not get deleted, it should be:

> https://stackoverflow.com/seriously/unikong

If it does get deleted, I've already downloaded a copy, so I could re-upload it to GitHub pages or something.

#### Update:

Adam Lear has stated in the comments on [Will Unikong be open-sourced?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320262/will-unikong-be-open-sourced), that the game will be kept on the CDN and probably made open-source.

> Open-sourcing, and leaving it up on the CDN. – [Adam Lear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320262/will-unikong-be-open-sourced#comment329381_320262)

Comment: I first thought that the link will be dead and you're trying to fool us. #AprilFool

Comment: Is it open source? Where can I find the source code?

Comment: @Meysam It's not open-source to my knowledge, but you can download the minified JS file.

Comment: *so I could re-upload it to GitHub pages or something* Do we legallly have the rights to distribute SO's files?

Comment: @A.L That's a legal gray area. I don't see a specific license on anything, but that doesn't stop sites like archive.org doing things like this on a massive scale. This is in part why current copyright rules are considered unfit for the internet. However past experience strongly suggests SO would not care.

Comment: It's also preserved in the Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20160401062857/http://stackoverflow.com/seriously/unikong

Comment: @DavidB archive.org is finicky about caching some resources, especially those loaded via JavaScript, so it may not cache everything properly. But Adam Lear said the game will stay up, and probably be open-sourced too.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara You make a good point. That said, it looks like this time, things may have worked out: http://web.archive.org/web/20160401062858js_/http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/unikong.js?v=710d92f5becf

Comment: The game is written in JavaScript, publicly accessible, and hasn't been obfuscated (only minified).  That effectively makes it open-source.  The only thing missing is an official statement affirming its status.  But if you want to look at and play with the code, there's already nothing stopping you.

Comment: The link returns a "page not found"

Comment: @MartinSmith I've added a mirror.