# Will Unikong be open-sourced?

Tags: discussion, unikong

I think it would be cool to open-source Unikong once April 1st is over, as was done last year for [StackEgg](https://github.com/StackExchange/stackegg).

Then we could keep playing forever :-)

(As a side note: if it is actually open-sourced, why not use GitHub's static HTML hosting, or leave it up on the CDN, so it  can actually be played ?)

Comment: Must be!!! Or the Unikong shall unleash his wrath onto @jeffAtwood! Free the Unikongs!

Comment: StackEgg related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252451/we-liked-stackegg-let-the-fun-continue

Comment: Unikong MSE related: [Play Unikong Forever](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277782/play-unikong-forever)

Comment: R.I.P. Productivity

Comment: Yeah, I'm gonna look into doing that next week.

Comment: @Adam: you mean the "Then we could keep playing forever" part?

Comment: @RadLexus Open-sourcing, and leaving it up on the CDN.

Comment: @AdamLear It's [currently down](http://stackoverflow.com/seriously/unikong) :(

Comment: @Rob I've put up a mirror over on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320238/will-unikong-be-available-after-april-1st/320241

Comment: If anyone is looking for the unminified version of Unikong, it's [here](http://dev.stackoverflow.com/content/js/unikong.js) (you have to scroll through Phaser first).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is officially done now, with the code at:

**https://github.com/StackExchange/unikong**

And it can be played [here](http://stackexchange.github.io/unikong). There's also some bugfixes and improvemnts, added after the game ran on Stack Overflow proper. Have fun :-)

Answer (score 15):

The game is hosted on GitHub now: https://unikong.github.io/

Comment: Thanks to [Alexander O'Mara](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3155639/alexander-omara) for [posting the link to the GitHub repo on my question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320241/473792)!

Comment: Who will solve questions now ? :D

Comment: This is neither official nor open-source.